# Telegram-bot. Запустить без интернета

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Есть телеграм-бот, который работает. Можно ли его как-то запустить без интернета из консоли. Т.е. чтобы в pycharm я мог имитировать передачу команд от пользователя. Например /start
Просьба объяснить как для последнего дурака. Я в этом деле около 0. Только начал.

Comment: Нет, офлайн не будет работать. А зачем? Если для тестов, то создайте еще одного бота, получите `token` и на нем обкатывайте

Comment: @ZxNuClear видимо цель презентовать школьный проект, а в школе интернет не берёт или глушат

Comment: да, именно для тестов. Поставили задачу создать тестового бота, по примеру рабочего.  
Например, я отправляю через консоль команду /start, бот реагирует и сохраняет в список сообщение, которое отправил в ответ на команду /start. Т.е. все должно работать без интернета.